# Remove jsonb_build_object from the output

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am creating a jsonb object using jsonb_build_object in PostgreSQL. The problem is that it adds jsonb_build_object column in the output. Please refer to the screenshot and query below:

[image]

```
     select  jsonb_build_object(
                    'country_name', country_name,
                    'country_code', country_code,
                    'currency_code', currency_code
                )
     from table
```

Is there any way to exclude jsonb_build_object from output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the query you are using. That should make it possible to give you a solution to the problem.

Comment: That is a formatting decision made by your (undisclosed) client program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pointed out by @jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035312/remove-jsonb-build-object-from-the-output#comment135804534_77035312), that's not PostgreSQL doing it, it's your client application or library fetching results of your query into a `json` structure where it injects the column/field name as a top-level key in order to be able to accommodate multiple columns in one structure.

You didn't specify how you wish to call the field holding the ouput of that function, so PostgreSQL just named it after the function, hence the `jsonb_build_object` top-level key, but according to the db it's the *field/column name*, not an internal part of the result. You can see what it looks like to the DB here: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/42KWFczo)

```sql
create table your_table as select 
  'Canada' as country_name, 
  'CA' as country_code, 
  'CAD' as currency_code;

select  jsonb_build_object(
                    'country_name', country_name,
                    'country_code', country_code,
                    'currency_code', currency_code
                )
from your_table;
```

| jsonb_build_object |
| --- |
| {"country_code": "CA", "country_name": "Canada", "currency_code": "CAD"} |

Notice that it's in the header, not in the actual field. To get rid of it, you need to peel that off in your client/app. It would be helpful if you updated the question to specify what client/library+language you're using and show how you obtained these records.

Comment: I am saving the query result as JSON using Python.

Comment: If you're getting them one by one then `result=result['jsonb_build_object']` will peel off that top level. [Demo](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zkk6czn6). Please remember to edit the question whenever you add more details - it's harder for others to follow if you leave additional info in separate comments.

Answer (score -1):

Try using CTE  (Common Table Expression) to achieve the desired output.

Here is the CTE Code;

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT jsonb_build_object(
        'country_name', country_name,
        'country_code', country_code,
        'currency_code', currency_code
    ) AS jsonb_data
    FROM table
)
SELECT jsonb_data
FROM cte;
```

Now the  'jsonb_build_object' has been excluded from the output.

Comment: The output will still contain jsonb_data

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
with temp_data as (
  select  jsonb_build_object(
                    'country_name', country_name,
                    'country_code', country_code,
                    'currency_code', currency_code
                )
     from table
)

select t->'jsonb_build_object' from temp_data t
```